# SQL Server SET DATEFIRST scope

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SS 2005 if that

I've seen sample code like

```
DECLARE @restore = SELECT @@DATEFIRST
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT datepart(dw,ADateTimeColumn) as MondayBasedDate,.... FROM famousShipwrecks --
SET DATEFIRST @restore
```

Suppose while the query is running another query sets DATEFIRST?

If another query relies on datefirst being 7 (for example) and doesn't set it, and runs while my query is running, that's his problem for not setting it?  or is there a better way to write queries that depend on a given day being day number 1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@@DATEFIRST is local to your session.  You can verify it by opening to tabs in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS). Execute this code in the first tab:

```
 SET DATEFIRST 5
```

And verify that it doesn't affect the other tab with:

```
select @@datefirst
```

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx).

Comment: So if you're writing a stored procedure that's going to constitute the entire session - as the one and only data source for a crystal report where there's no chance the SP will ever change or be reused - then there's no point restoring the original value?

Comment: Agreed, but maybe Crystal Reports caches the connection. So it can't hurt to restore the original value.

Answer (score 3):

You can forget about `DATEPART(weekday, DateColumn)` and `@@DATEFIRST` and instead calculate the day of the week yourself.

For Monday based weeks (Europe) simplest is:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '17530101', ADateTimeColumn) % 7 + 1 AS MondayBasedDay
FROM famousShipwrecks
```

For Sunday based weeks (America) use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '17530107', ADateTimeColumn) % 7 + 1 AS SundayBasedDay
FROM famousShipwrecks
```

This works fine ever since January 1st respectively 7th, 1753.

Comment: [Like old Philip Stanhope used to say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310588/3585500), "Those who forget history are doomed to use DATEFIRST."

Answer (score 2):

Just an additional point, if you want to avoid setting DATEFIRST you can just incorporate the value of DATEFIRST in your query to find your required day as :

```
    SELECT (datepart(dw,ADateTimeColumn) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7)  as 'MondayBasedDate'
    , ...
    FROM famousShipwrecks --
```

Then you dont need to worry about restoring it at all!

Comment: This does not give a MondayBasedDate, but one where sunday is 1 and monday is 2.

To make monday 1 and sunday 7 use the following changes:

datepart(WEEKDAY, ADateTimeColumn) + @@DATEFIRST - 2 ) % 7 + 1

Answer (score 0):

To setup a parameterized first day of the week, the following should work

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfWeek INT = 1;
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = '2015-07-14 8:00:00';
SELECT (DATEPART(weekday, @DateTime) + @@DateFirst - @FirstDayOfWeek - 1) % 7 + 1;
```